# python импорт пакета из родительского

Tags: python, импорт

```
.
`-- project
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- a
    |   |-- __init__.py
    |   `-- a.py
    `-- b
        |-- __init__.py
        `-- b.py
```

project/b.py:

```py
from .. import a
```

Выскакивает эксепшн:

```
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

Что я делаю не так в этой жизни?

Comment: Используйте `from project import a`.

Comment: Это конечно замечательно, но что если корневой папки нет в sys.path? Менять его тоже не хотелось бы, головняк как для себя, так и для юзеров

Comment: А Вам и не следует об этом заботиться. Вы делаете пакет. Исполняемый файл будет находиться за его пределами. `Python` будет знать об этом пакете и импорты внутри него отлично разрешатся.

Comment: Господи, как всё просто оказлось. Спасибо, извините.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `from project import a`.